# Move the cursor to the start after auto-completion

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit, qcompleter

I have a small program where I used a line edit for auto-completion. After selecting the text, my cursor goes to end of the text. So how to set my cursor to the starting position?

My code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QCompleter, QLineEdit, QStringListModel

def get_data(model):
   model.setStringList(["completion_xxxxxxxxxx", "data_yyyyyyyyyy", "goes_ccccccccc", "here"])

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    edit = QLineEdit()
    edit.setCursorPosition(0)
    completer = QCompleter()
    edit.setCompleter(completer)

    model = QStringListModel()
    completer.setModel(model)
    get_data(model)

    edit.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

But I want to show it like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the cursor to move *after* the completion has finished, you can use the completer's `activated` signal with a single-shot timer, like this:

```
completer.activated.connect(
    lambda: QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: edit.home(False)))
```

Comment: thank you  so much for reply i have a one more doubt can i ask?

Comment: i want to remove the particular cell of the border in table widget i tried so many ways .some methods are there for to remove the complete borders but i didn't find any method for to remove the particular row of the border in table widget if you knew can you please tell me.

Comment: @gowthami For that, you should start a new question, because it is on a totally different subject.

Comment: sir many times i asked in stack overflow but no one is giving the answer but in my project i need that topic.THANK YOU

Comment: @gowthami I looked at [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10242478/gowthami?tab=questions), but I cannot see one about that topic. Which one do you mean?

Comment: sir  i  posted  my question if you knew please tell me

Comment: sir i have one doubt can i ask?